# Why high air speed at flat surface don't always produce low pressure?

Tags: aerodynamics, fluid-dynamics

**Can you explain why flat surfaces don't produce low pressure in both experiments ,even air has high speed in both case?**

**1)experiment where flat surface DON'T produce low pressure:**

**[http://www.cabrillo.edu/~jwelch/bernoulli/bernoulli.wmv](http://www.cabrillo.edu/%7Ejwelch/bernoulli/bernoulli.wmv)**

**2)experiment where flat surface produce low pressure:**
[video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JuoSJz3SRU&feature=emb_logo)

[image]

**3)experiment where curved surface produce low pressure(as always):**
[video3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-SAQtODAQw)

If car has **flat floor** 5cm from ground,will this floor produce low pressure or we must add some curvature to lower pressure?

What is key for low pressure,airflow  speed or airflow curvature?

Comment: The person who produced the second video was actually promoting his own book, so if you can get a copy you will find the answer Physics Demonstration Apparatus Paperback - January 1, 2010 by Martin C. Sagendorf (Author)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

Speed does not produce low pressure, *increasing* it does!

Bernoulli's equation says that for a fluid flow, in absence of elements doing work on the stream or having work done on them by the stream¹, $p + \frac12\rho v^2$ stays constant². But it does not tell us what constant. You can have flows with any combination of $p$ and $v$, and all will still satisfy the Bernoulli's equation.

## Straight box in the first video

The blowers increase the energy of the air inside the hose. The energy can manifest as either static pressure, $p$, or dynamic pressure, $\frac12\rho v^2$. How it chooses? Well, if the static pressure $p$ inside the hose is higher than outside, the pressure gradient accelerates the air out, converting the static pressure to dynamic, and if the static pressure in the hose is lower, the gradient decelerates the air. So the flow will quickly stabilize so that the static pressure matches the ambient³, and the added energy determines the velocity.

Therefore there is the same static pressure everywhere and the box between the two nozzles has no reason to move.

## Curved surfaces in the first video

The other experiments in the first video are *not* explainable by Bernoulli's equation alone, but instead effects of inertia and viscosity have to be taken into account. As the air flows around the curvature:

- If the curvature is towards the stream, the air starts hitting the wall and needs to turn around it. Since it has mass, it requires force to turn it, which creates additional pressure on the wall, and a pressure gradient forms near it turning the air molecules further away. Bernoulli's principle tells us the velocity will, somewhat counter-intuitively⁴, decrease, but that is just a side-effect; we already know the pressure is increased.
- It the curvature is away from the stream, the air would want to just continue straight. However there can't remain a wedge of a stagnant air behind the receding surface, because it would have higher pressure that forces it to move, and viscosity prevents forming another flow in a wedge shape to fill in, so the original stream sticks to the surface. And this means a pressure gradient again establishes that overcomes its inertia, this time with low pressure near the surface.

  Bernoulli's principle tells us the velocity, again somewhat counter-intuitively⁵, increases, but that is again just a side-effect; we already know the pressure is reduced.

## Second video

Last, the experiment in the second video relies on the fact that the air is expanding in multiple directions, so the cross-section available to it increases⁶.

According to the above, the velocity on the outer edge will be such that the static pressure matches ambient. But before it gets there, it has to squeeze through the still much smaller area near where the hose is connected. Since the same volume⁷ of air needs to get through both per second (due to conservation of mass), and to do that, it must move faster. And since it moves faster, its static pressure is lower, and this creates the pressure differential that pulls the plate towards the nozzle.

This is the only of the experiments that is actually demonstrating Bernoulli's principle.

## Curvature v.s. speed

You see some of the cases are governed by one and some by the other. Fluid dynamics is extremely complex and difficult to calculate – the [“easy solvability”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_existence_and_smoothness) or [Navier-Stokes equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) (that describe fluid dynamics; Bernoulli's equation is included in the set) is [famous](https://www.xkcd.com/1851/).

Generally, the curvature works in most situations, but watch out for aerodynamic stall (when the angle is too steep for viscosity to keep the fluid flowing ‘orderly’), while velocity only works when you have control over it, which is generally just in closed pipes.

---

¹ Bernoulli's equation simply expresses the internal energy of a fluid. If you do work on it you are adding energy, so that energy has to be added in the equation.

² Potential energy term omitted for brevity.

³ Dynamics of jet and rocket nozzles is much more complicated, but at the low velocities involved it holds pretty well.

⁴ It is counter-intuitive because it looks like the air has to move through less space, but since there is no opposite wall, it is free to expand as it suits it.

⁵ This is counter-intuitive because it looks like the air needs to expand to more space, but again there is no other wall, so it can pull more air from far and wide to fill that space.

⁶ I am not completely sure this case does not involve some additional effects.

⁷ Actually the same mass, and to be accurate we should include the adiabatic expansion of air, but for the speeds involved air can be approximated as incompressible.

Comment: Great explanation about how a jet can have higher dynamic pressure, but still the same static pressure as the air around it.

Comment: @Jan Hudec, so if car has flat floor which is 100% parallel to the ground,then pressure between floor and ground is same as ambient?

Comment: @NoahPrandtl, Yes, if it was completely flat, including the leading and trailing edges, only a layer of air of constant height would flow below it, so there would be no reason for any velocity changes to occur and therefore no reason for pressure changes either. It has to squeeze the air in front and expand it again at the back. And then you can either talk about the pressure in the middle being lower from Bernoulli's principle or pressure gradients and momentum changes due to curvature – both conservation of momentum and second law of motion hold at the same time.

Comment: @NoahPrandtl, if there is a car body on top of the flat plate, so there is a flat plate with some arbitrary shape on top, that shape is going to cause a higher pressure on top of the flat plate due to the stagnation, and some low pressure (assuming separation or other losses from the body) behind the body. This will actually create some downwash at the LE and some upwash at the TE of the floor, which will actually give downforce. This is how a racecar splitter works, but you need to have the obstruction above to generate the circulation at the LE/TE

Comment: @StuartBuckingham circulation basically requires that the stagnation points are at different height, and if it should be producing downforce, the TE one must be higher. Which in turn means there is some upward slope on the “underside” (where the division is the stagnation points, so it can be just the tail gate).

Comment: @JanHudec you can definitely create a net lift / downforce with a cambered airfoil with no incidence, but obviously not for a symmetric airfoil. I was explaining that with an obstruction (car body) on the top surface, it will break the symmetry of the vehicle, and due to the stagnation on the car body, there will be downwash infront of the floor LE and upwash after the floor TE. Tried to expand my answer below, which hopefully helps.

Comment: BTW +1 for the XKCD link! MHD is crazy

Comment: @JanHudec,If you put curvature towards stream ,pressure will be reduced again,why do you say that pressure will be increased? look at video where air is blown out into curvature and pressure is reduced so "wing"  lift up..https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-SAQtODAQw

Comment: I would definitely not bring viscosity into this. Potential flow is a really useful tool for many applications, and it assumes perfect inviscid flow. Flow is able to continue tangential to a surface anywhere, but what would fill the void that is left behind? We cannot create a vacuum, so therefore the void can only be filled with the flow (keep it attached), or have recirculated flow fill the void (seperation). Which of these occur really is a function of the boundary layer.

Comment: @StuartBuckingham,Yes viscostiy is not reason why airflow follow curved surface,inviscid flow follow curved surface  very well but because of pressure gradient,here proffesor talk about it at 17:53 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aa2kBZAoXg0

Comment: Fantastic that you have done your research! This is a very useful video.

Comment: @NoahPrandtl, well, right, it is kinda much more complex – and there is basically no longer any quantitative explanation any more. It's now ‘the math says it can look like this, but not like that’. And note that viscosity *is* still involved, just in a more complex way than simply flushing out the wedge of still air.

Comment: @JanHudec,"Last, the experiment in the second video relies on the fact that the hose is thinner than the gap all around the plate through which the air eventually leaves⁶."You mean ticker? hose cross section is larger than gap between plates cross section?

Comment: @NoahPrandtl, no, I do mean the hose is thinner. The cross-section of the ‘nozzle’ is the distance between the plates – which might be a bit smaller than the hose diameter – times the circumference of the plates, which is much, much larger. That means the air is slowing down from the hose to the edge of the plates, and because it's static pressure matches ambient at that edge, it must be lower in the middle.

Comment: @NoahPrandtl … but the hose itself is not actually relevant. The air is expanding from the centre outwards in any case.

Comment: @JanHudec,Hi ,do know maybe answer for my question :https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/80224/how-much-planform-effects-change-local-aoa

Answer (score 1):

The ping-pong ball is floating due to the Coandă effect and Bernoulli principle. I edited your picture to explain what I think is going on with the flat plate. For the suction effect of formula one vehicles however, they employ Bernoulli and other principles, the diffuser, and until the 1980s, suction skirts coupled with the venturi effect. Please refer to [this link](https://auto.howstuffworks.com/auto-racing/motorsports/formula-one3.htm). Here is another link to [F1 aerodynamics](https://www.drive.com.au/motor-news/the-physics-of-formula-one-20100824-13kqi) and a [detailed video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOZgEvJbnlc)

One more thing, I think the gap between the plates has a critical distance as can be seen in the video.

[image: Bernoulli_flat_plate]

Comment: ,http://www.cabrillo.edu/~jwelch/bernoulli/bernoulli.wmv explain why here flat surface dont produce pressure drop?

Comment: Maybe it needs the top plate. In the cabrillo video they only use one surface.

Answer (score 1):

In the video with the flat plate, the flow is much faster on the side closest to the other plate, and so the pressure is lower than the other side of the plate, which is exposed to atmospheric pressure. That attraction of the plates that you see is due to the pressure difference between the near-side (suction) and the far-side (ambient).

To generate downforce on a floor, both speed and curvature are important considerations. If you just have a flat plate travelling parallel to the ground, the airspeed is identical on the top and bottom surfaces, and therefore you have no net force. To get a lower pressure, you need to have the flow accelerated on the bottom side of the flat plate. To do this you could do work on the fluid (e.g. the good ole' Brabham BT46), but this is outlawed in most racing. Instead, you can use curvature to make the flow on the bottom faster.

If you have a flat plate with a car body on top of the flat plate, so there is a flat plate with some arbitrary shape on top, that shape is going to cause a higher pressure on top of the flat plate due to the stagnation in front of the car body, and some low pressure (assuming separation or other losses from the body) behind the car body. This will actually create some downwash at the LE and some upwash at the TE of the floor, which will actually give downforce. This is exactly how a racecar splitter works, but you need to have the obstruction above to generate the circulation at the LE/TE. When you look at pictures of racecars with splitters like below, you can see that the front is turned up slightly because the oncoming flow will have some downwash
[image: Source https://www.roadandtrack.com/motorsports/news/a18100/dtm-racing-defined/]

At the back of the car, having a diffuser is going to generate much more load than just a flat plate extending out the back.

Comment: look at this experiment :http://www.cabrillo.edu/~jwelch/bernoulli/bernoulli.wmv   ,why here flate surface dont produce low pressure?

Comment: Interesting! There is no mechanism for a pressure differential across the shear layer between the blower output (jet) and the ambient air (assuming subsonic flow). Therefore the static pressure inside the jet is the same as outside of the jet (ambient). The work done by the blower to increase the Total Pressure above ambient Total Pressure is the dynamic pressure here in the jet.

Comment: @NoahPrandtl hopefully this answers your question. Jan Hudec's answer about the pressure in the airflow fed from the blower is also very useful.

Comment: Yes it is but I dont unerstand why he wrote that curvature toward stream will increase pressure? here you can see  air is blown out toward curvature and produce low pressure which lift wing up..https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-SAQtODAQw

Comment: Yes he was talking about a **concave** surface, which gives a pressure rise because the flow has to accelerate **normal to the wall** like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force. Of course when we are accelerating the flow towards the center of rotation (located within the fluid volume), there must exist an equal and opposite force (Newtons third law), which is exhibited as an outward pressure on the wall.

Comment: ,I didnt understand  him well that he is talking about concave surface...now it is OK

Answer (score 0):

Bernoulli principle is often misused if one doesn't understand the limitations. Bernoulli's principle applies to a flow that is **incompressible** and **isentropic**:

- Incompressible means that the flow must be fairly slow, like Mach << 0.3. In both of your videos, this condition is definitely satisfied.
- Isentropic means that there are no viscous losses or energy input (like flow passing through a fan). This is where the problem lies.

In video #1, the flow passes through a fan and then discharges to a flat surface. For simplicity, let's say that air near the bottom of the object is static relative to it (see diagram below). For the flow after the fan, any point along its trajectory (or in fancy term, within the streamtube) is isentropic, so Bernoulli readily applies. However, any flow not passing through the fan, such as any point underneath the object, is *not* isentropic relative to the stuff within the streamtube on top. So Bernoulli cannot be applied.

[image: Video #1 explanation]

In actual fact, this high velocity jet, a little distance away from the fan, would essentially have the same pressure as the ambient air. Otherwise, you'd see the stream of air curving away, which would be weird. Therefore, there would be no suction on the surface either.

In video #2, as the plate is squeezed toward the tube opening, you essentially get a venturi effect: for the same mass flow rate, there's an acceleration in airspeed. Since there's no energy input, Bernoulli readily applies here. Higher speed translates to lower pressure, thereby giving rise to suction.

Comment: in video#2 air is blown  out from tube not sucked.Look at 1:26 how air goes outward..

Comment: @NoahPrandtl Thanks. Modified the last paragraph.