# Does low pressure induces high velocity or high velocity induces low pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Does low pressure induces high velocity or high velocity induces low pressure? I am wandering what is the cause and what is the result. I mean i.e. Bernoulli principle or situation in the core of a vortex.

Comment: are you asking about Bernoulli's principle or something else?

Comment: what are you asking here? could you be more specific, velocity of the airplane ot the wind around.

Comment: My fault, question edited.

Comment: @Konrad this one may be migrated to Physics Stack too, but is a great fundamental building block question.  High air velocity is caused by pressure **differential** between higher and lower pressure.  A fast moving air stream of air (or water) will pull air away from a surface, creating an attraction of the surface to the airstream (Coanda effect).  The latter seems to explain lift from airflow over the *top* of the wing, while lift from the bottom is action/reaction of the (moving) wing pushing air down.

Comment: And what about i.e. wingtip vortex? There is a low pressure in a vortex core and higher and higher pressure if we move away from the core. In this case isn't (angular) velocity a cause of pressure drop in a core (highest angular velocity in a core and slow decrease if we move away from a core)?

Comment: @Konrad  vortexes are interesting in that the rotation does carry angular momentum but only in the plane of rotation. (not like a tornado)  Pressure can equalize (from top or bottom) after the vortex drifts away from the wing, but the rotor motion will take longer to dissipate (from drag).

Comment: the walls of a tornado can act as a pressure "barrier" (by rapid rotation), but lower pressure is maintained from the top, and the ground acts as a "seal" from the bottom.

Comment: @Konrad, the downward velocity in the wake is due to the work done on the air by the wing, so it does *not* reduce the pressure. As the air leaves the trailing edge, it has additional downward velocity compared to the free stream, but is at ambient pressure.  See also https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/80119/why-high-air-speed-at-flat-surface-dont-always-produce-low-pressure?rq=1

Comment: … only as the wake interacts with the surrounding air mass and rolls to a vortex does the pressure gradient form that generates the centripetal force needed to keep the air rotating, and here Bernoulli's principle tells us it is accompanied by further increase in velocity in the core of the vertex. But the vortex exists because it has more energy than the free stream, not because of this pressure decrease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither! The cause is wing moving through the air, and the effect is a fairly complex flow pattern around it that produces lift (and wake vortex).

We know that the flow obeys certain laws (that are largely averaging of the microscopic laws governing individual molecules). One of them is law of conservation of energy, which for fluids is known as Bernoulli's equation. But that's just one equation with many free variables, so alone it is not enough to explain anything. You need the complete set of [Navier-Stokes equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) to be able to describe the flow.

The equations are partially differential, and need to be evaluated for every point in space and time, which can only be done approximately and requires a computer.

There is only a few conclusions that can be made using conservation laws without this, the most important probably is the existence of downwash. The third law of motion tells us that if upward force, lift, is applied to the wing, downward force is applied to the air, and second law of motion tells us that this force accelerates the air downward. The boundary between downward moving air behind the wing and the still air outside the span is the wake vortex.

But again, neither is cause and effect. The laws of physics work both ways. They just tell us that these phenomena always occur together. But the cause is the situation. We just know that both or neither will occur.